# Database related query

Tags: sql

In one of the interview, I was asked a question on sql query.
The query is for employee table

```
ID     Name     Salary
1      emp 1    10000
2      emp 2    20000
3      emp 3    30000
4      emp 4    40000
...
```

I have to update employee salary as say if it is below 10000 increment by 500
if it is between 10000 to 20000 update by 600
if it is between 20000 to 30000 update by 700
and continuous till last record in the table.
There's hundreds of thousands of rows in the table.

How to create script for this?

Comment: Please format your data.

Comment: BTW in which dbms you were asked to write this query?

Comment: On SQL Server Query the question was being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
UPDATE employee 
SET Salary=
CASE WHEN Salary < 10000 THEN Salary + 500
CASE WHEN Salary >= 10000 and Salary < 20000  then Salary+600
CASE WHEN Salary >= 20000 and Salary < 30000  then Salary+700
ELSE Salary END
```

Comment: in which dbms are you firing above query?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But in employee table salary may by changing in that case , how many case statement I need to add in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Your description doesn't say what to do if the salary is above 30000. I'll assume the salary is to be updated by 800 in that case. With that assumption, you can do:

```
SELECT *, (
    (Salary<10000)?(Salary+500):(
    (Salary>=10000 AND Salary < 20000)? (Salary + 600):(
    (Salary>=20000 AND Salary < 30000)? (Salary + 700): 
    (Salary + 800)) 
 ))) AS NewSalary FROM employee;
```

Hope this gives you an idea.